# How do I position a two views, on top of each other, at certain coordinates, in Android?

Tags: android, xml, layout, absolute, android-framelayout

I have two views, a game view and an admob view.

I want the game view positioned at 0, 0 and with fill parent (so it covers the whole screen), and I want to admob view to be located at 50, 50 (just an example coordinates) and with fill_content.

**How do I do this using FrameLayout in Android? Doesn't matter if its via layout-xml or programatically.**

I've spent a lot of time searching for examples and tweaking the code myself without any luck.

Specific example code is more appreciate than a link to how views generally work in Android.

Update 1:

This is my current code.

### Via XML-layout:

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/framelayout" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <se.meendo.mapgame.MainMenuView android:id="@+id/mainmenuview" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="50dip" 
android:layout_marginRight="50dip"
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

Java:

```
public class BannerActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.banner);

        MainMenuView mmv = (MainMenuView) findViewById(R.id.mainmenuview);
        if (mmv == null) {
            mmv = new MainMenuView(this);
        }

        AdView ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
        if (ad != null) {
            ad = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14da0cf5ab5ef7");

            AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
            request.setTesting(true);
            ad.loadAd(request);

        }

    }

}
```

### Via pure Java

```
public class BannerActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(this);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        MainMenuView mmview = new MainMenuView(this);
        LayoutParams pl = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layout.addView(mmview, pl);

        AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "****");
        LayoutParams pelle = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        pelle.setMargins(240, 430, 0, 240);
        adView.setLayoutParams(pelle);

        //      adView.setAdListener(new MyAdListener(this));

        AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
        request.setTesting(true);
        adView.loadAd(request);

        LayoutParams pl2 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        pl2.setMargins(240, 430, 0, 240);
        //      layout.addView(adView, pl2);
        layout.addView(adView);

        setContentView(layout);

    }

}
```

Here I trid with coordinates 240, 430 - since I know the banner is 320x50 and I wanted to try and put in the center.

The results

XML-layout: The MainMenu-view showed but not admob-view
Pure Java: The MainMenu-view showed, and the admob-view. But the admob view is shown at 0, 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add just layout_gravity attribute in **com.google.ads.AdView** view as follow

```
android:layout_gravity="left"
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap both the views in a FrameLayout. To set the admob view to 50, 50:

```
android:layout_marginLeft="50dip" 
android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

This should be enough. What code have you tried? Can you post it in your answer?